# Setting a value to chrome.storage.local is not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

storage.local.set for setting some value in my chrome extension.
I am trying to do this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var username = $(".username").val();
var userpassword = $(".password").val();

    $(".signin").click(function(){
chrome.storage.local.set({"email" : username});
    chrome.storage.local.set({"userpassword" : password});
    })
});
```

I am getting this error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
```

Can someone help me with get and set chrome.storage.local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add `storage` for `permissions` field in `manifest.json`